# How to convert curl request to browser URL

Tags: http, url, curl, browser

Is it possible to generate equivalent browser URL from all curl request.
Example : 
If I am executing following

`curl -v -X GET -H "Host:something.com"  "http://foo.com/some?appAction=xux&a=1&b=2"`

What will corresponding browser URL.(which I can hit directly in browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *"equivalent"* you mean *"Using a host header claiming a different host than mentioned in the request URI"*, then the answer is: no, you can't. The browser will pull the host header from the entered URI.

You may be able to rewrite the headers using browser plugins.